# ActiveRecord `unscoped` returns models from a different database but with the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, database-migration, validates-uniqueness-of

**Update:** Well, so I debugged Rails, and found out it happens because both my tables are named the same.

`validates_uniquness_of` calls `unscoped` on the model's class. `unscoped` returns all rows from the legacy table.

**Original Post:** I'm creating a migration of legacy data from one Rails application to another (both DBs are Postgresql).

My new application has a `validates_uniqueness_of` validation for one of the models.

As explained [here](http://snabb.me/blog/2013-migrating-legacy-database-into-rails), I created Legacy models classes that establish a connection to the legacy DB (using `establish_connection :legacy`). During the application-level migration, I copy the model data from the legacy table to create a new model in my new application, row by row. The process fails with the first model creation, since the uniqueness validation fails (**even though the new DB is still empty**).

This makes me believe `validates_uniqueness_of` takes the legacy DB into account as well for some reason.

The table for the model with the validation, has the same name both in the legacy database and in the new one.

Comment: Although I haven't experienced this situation, there are a number of methods you could try to get around it. 1: Analyse the Rails code to see if you're right in your analysis of the situation. If you are, write a patch and maybe issue a pull request. You can use the debugger to step through the validation to find out why it's kicking in. 2: Sidestep the problem by writing your own uniqueness validation method. You can always swap back after the import. 3: Another sidestep: if you're sure the legacy data is good, comment out the validator until the import is complete.

Comment: Double-check using the console that the models are working as you expect and accessing the correct databases.

Comment: When I access the models, each one connects to the right DB, e.g: `User.count != LegacyUser.count`. I tried creating the models with `validate: false`, which works, but all my models are then considered invalid unless I disconnect the legacy database, which is something I want to avoid.

Comment: So you want to keep the legacy database connected going forward?

Comment: No, but I don't want to have any moment where my models are invalid. The effect I perceive is clearly not what's meant to be.

Comment: This is an interesting one. If I get a moment I may try to recreate your issue. In the meantime, can you effectively check for validity by hand in the console? (As in, run queries to look for the unique field, taking into account whether the model is saved or not.) If you can, write your own validator method. If you can't, something is seriously screwy. (Or you've made a mistake with your set-up.)